# "Query Too Complex" on a Union between multiple queries

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I've searched for this topic and came across a few reasons for why "Query Too Complex" may pop up, but I find my situation to be somewhat unique.

I am combining a lot of queries. I found out the hard way there is a limit to how many queries/tables can be included in a query. I read that number is 32, while I tried to run a union of 60 (giving me an error). I resolved this by creating four intermediate queries that union <20 queries each. That worked for a while, (both the intermediate query and the final query) until I recently added some more queries to the unions. Now, the intermediate queries run just fine, but the last query that unions the four intermediate unions throws the error "Query too complex".

I've read suggestions to

1. Create named queries and union those (as opposed to Unioning select statements), which I had done
2. Check the underlying queries for errors, which I did, and none of them have issues when run independently
3. Confirm all columns are identical in name and type which they are

Here's the query throwing the error:

```
Select Usys_Q_M_Union1_1.* From Usys_Q_M_Union1_1
UNION ALL
Select Usys_Q_M_Union1_2.* From Usys_Q_M_Union1_2
UNION ALL
Select Usys_Q_M_Union1_3.* From Usys_Q_M_Union1_3
UNION ALL 
Select Usys_Q_M_Union1_4.* From Usys_Q_M_Union1_4
ORDER BY [MetricName];
```

If more information is needed, I'll try to provide.

Comment: Why need for UNION? Perhaps you should not have all these separate tables and should be 1 table with another identifier field?

Comment: does removing the `ORDER BY` at the end solve the problem?

Comment: Your problem is not the union query but one, some, or all of the subqueries.

Comment: @June - That is my plan today, to see if that resolves it.

Comment: @Cha - Unfortunately not.

Comment: @Gustav - If all the queries and subqueries run just fine, except for this one, how can I determine what is causing the issue? If it is a sub-query, what should I look for to potentially be the problem?

Comment: Remove on at a time.

Comment: you should seriously reconsider your design. it is rather unusual to have the level of nested queries you mention. if it becomes too problematic to troubleshoot, that's usually a good indicator that your solution has become too complex